# Android application stopped

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i was trying to connect a database that i created using SQLite. i dont have any errors, but whenever i try to run the app on emulator, the application automatically stops working as soon as it starts.. heres the code which has only one activity that connects database and extract data from it and displays it

MANIFEST :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sampledb"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sampledb.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
  </manifest>
```

heres the layout file that has a textview and a radio group in which the text is extraxted from database:

XML : In the following XML file i have created a text view where i would like to put the question and radio buttons and its texts where i would like to put choices. heres the code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainScreen" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sample" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rg1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
             />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />

          <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
    </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/explanation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Explanation" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

In the Database i have few coloumns that has a question and few choices which i tried to use it as a text for radiobuttons.
    the activity code :

```
package com.example.sampledb;

import java.util.Locale;
import com.example.sampledb.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView Question;
    RadioGroup G1;
    RadioButton B1, B2, B3, B4;
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Question= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);
        G1=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg1);
        B1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        B2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        B3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        B4=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio3);
            SQLiteDatabase db;
            db = openOrCreateDatabase("vocablearner.db",
                SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        db.setVersion(1);
        db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());


        Cursor cur = db.query("MainTable", null, null, null, null, null,null);
         if (cur != null ) {
                if  (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                      do {
    String Quest = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
    String ans1 = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("C1"));
    String ans2 = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("C2"));
    String ans3 = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("C3"));
    String ans4 = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("C4"));
    //String crt = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Ccrt"));
    Question.setText(Quest);
    B1.setText(ans1);
    B2.setText(ans2);
    B3.setText(ans3);
    B4.setText(ans4);

                      }while (cur.moveToNext()); }  }   }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    } }     `
```

Here i have used a method openorcreatedatabase to define the database that i saved in assets folder and i have used cursor to extract the data.

In database file,the _id is made as primary key ( the questions ) and the coloumns c1 c2 c3 c4 are answers to that.

what changes should i make to run this code? Should i upload the database contents too?? and is there any other ways to use the database in android?

Here i have used a method openorcreatedatabase to define the database that i saved in assets folder and i have used cursor to extract the data.

In database file,the _id is made as primary key ( the questions ) and the coloumns c1 c2 c3 c4 are answers to that.

what changes should i make to run this code? Should i upload the database contents too?? and is there any other ways to use the database in android?

Comment: @Arjun I know that in your part of the world it is common to start a new paragraph with some spacing but it will totally confuse the formatter here on SO. So for the next time: Don't do it, just start writing at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Have you considered using a SqliteOpenHelper()?  It would certainly help clean up your onCreate() method.  Also, consider doing your db operations in a background thread.  Vogella has a nice tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: "I have no errors".  Yes you do.  You might not have *compile* time errors, but you do have a runtime error.  The two are not connected since to get the latter, you must fix the former.

Answer (score -1):

Check if you need to add any permissions in your manifest. Like writing to your external memory.

Comment: This is not an answer.  It should be a comment.

Comment: i have changed permission in manifest and i learned to use query() method in a proper way.. thanks a lot all to help this beginner :)